# captcha in php codeigniter showing fatal error

Tags: php, codeigniter, config, captcha

i am completely new to codeigniter, i have created a captcha using an online tutorial for my login form in codeigniter. i get the following error while loading my login page:

**> Fatal error: Call to undefined function base_url() in**

```
    $config = array(
        'img_path'      => 'captcha_images/',
        'img_url'       => base_url().'captcha_images/',
        'img_width'     => '150',
        'img_height'    => 50,
        'word_length'   => 8,
        'font_size'     => 16
    );
    $captcha = create_captcha($config);
```

`i dont have any folder named 'captcha_images', all i have is a controller for captcha,config and the view in login. As am new to this, is it because i dont have a folder or i didnt call any library? please help me with this. thanks in advance`

Comment: have you defined your base_url in your config files?

Comment: @sauhardnc, yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to 
`application/config/autoload.php`
Write this line below (You will find codeigniter nice documentation at line 90)
`$autoload['helper'] = array('url');`

This will autoload url helper.
`base_url() function is defined in url helper`

**You can manually load this for a particular controller**

Wrire this line `$this->load->helper('url');` Within controller constructor or

`Controller action function`

For more information about base_url [click](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/url_helper.html)

[Create CAPTCHA in codeigniter](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/captcha_helper.html)

Comment: You defined any base_url() function if yes comment out that function. Restart server. It's a common problem for beginner. Did you set your base url at application/config/config.php ?

Comment: yes, i have set base url in config.php. i have this in my autoload php $autoload['helper'] = array('html','form','url','language','date','string','security','globalfunctions','captcha');

Comment: when i added captcha, this problem is coming

Comment: I have added a codeigniter CAPTCHA  creation official doc link  follow this.

Comment: While @jobayersozib is pointing you in the right direction, nowadays it's a lot more user-friendly, safer and easier to implement some level of Google's reCAPTCHA. Have you considered that? Codeigniter's CAPTCHA library requires a lot more processing on your side (needs GD, databases, loading truetype fonts, etc... and the Captcha that's produced is quite easy to break for a motivated attacker).